# Clip not playing sound a second time

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I have a method that plays a sound. It works the first time, but in the second play I cannot hear the sound.
First I have the AudioInputStream instantiated in the constructor:

```
private AudioInputStream audio;

public AudioTest() {
        try {
            audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(PATH).getAbsoluteFile());
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
        }

}
```

And the method that plays the sound:

```
private void play() {
        try {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audio);
            clip.setFramePosition(0); 
            clip.start();     
        } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException e) {
        }
}
```

The first time I hear the audio but not the second time. Why?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the `Clip` first:

```
clip.close();
```

Comment: Before the open method right? Sorry, it did not work out, and I did not hear the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try getting a new `AudioInputStream` every time before getting a `Clip`, in the beginning of your `play()` method?

Meaning try to add this line in the beginning of the method:

`audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(PATH).getAbsoluteFile());`

Comment: The whole point of Clip is to not have to load the sound each time. It was made to allow you to play it from memory.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner I implemented a program that makes up melodies and plays them. The notes were played by Clips. I reused the same Clips and resetted them everytime (like they're meant to), and it sounded unconsistent and really bad. Someone suggested I don't reuse the same Clips but get new ones each time, and now it works perfectly (yeah it's odd). So it's worth a try.

Comment: Curious. Short files do load as Clips much more quickly than long notes, so there were probably other factors involved. If you are loading new each time, better to use SourceDataLine than Clip. I'd have to see more of the program to try to understand your result. Java can be pretty unruly when it comes to real time sound guarantees, especially when spanning multiple threads. And with Microsoft OS (system clock is only accurate to approximately 15 milliseconds) it gets even worse. E.g., triggering sound via button clicks or mouse movement crosses threads, is difficult to handle well.

Comment: Yeah, I guess Clip isn't meant for 'performance-critical' stuff like playing music, so it was actually faster to instantiate a new Clip than reuse functionality of the current one, for some reason. Who knows

Answer (score 0):

Try this: make your Clip an instance variable (and be private). When you initialize the Clip, leave it in an open state.

For the method where you play your clip, only do these two things: (1) move the frame position or microsecond position back to 0, (2) call the clip's start() method.

Do not reinitialize. Do not close. Do not reopen.

Did you look at the spec on Clip?
Concerning the open() method:

> Invoking this method on a line which is already open is illegal and
>   may result in an IllegalStateException.

Concerning the idea of close() followed by open():

> Note that some lines, once closed, cannot be reopened. Attempts to
>   reopen such a line will always result in a LineUnavailableException.

When you are sure you are not going to invoke the clip any more, that's the time to close() the clip.

The Java Tutorials could be clearer, but here's their link, too:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html

A LOT of people must only "kinda" read this (or read it and not understand) because a so many get confused and try to initialize and open a clip with each playback, and this is really inefficient. The playback won't even start until the entire data file has been loaded into memory, which adds needless latency.